# How can scrapy crawl more urls?

Tags: python, scrapy

as we see:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
    items = []

    for site in sites:
        item = Website()
        item['name'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = site.select('//a[contains(@href, "http")]/@href').extract()
        item['description'] = site.select('text()').extract()
        items.append(item)

    return items
```

scrapy just get a page response,and find urls in the page response.  I think it is just a surface crawl ！！

But  I want more urls with the definded depth .

what can I do to implement it ??

thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand your question, but I noticed several problems in your code, some of them could be related to your question (see the comments in the code):

```
sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
items = []

for site in sites:
    item = Website()
    # this extracts a list, so i guess .extract()[0] is expected
    item['name'] = site.select('a/text()').extract() 
    # '//a[...]' maybe you expect that this gets the links within the `site`, but it actually get the links from the entire page; you should use './/a[...]'.
    # And, again, this returns a list, not a single url.
    item['url'] = site.select('//a[contains(@href, "http")]/@href').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation on Requests and Responses](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html).

As you scrape the first page, you gather some links that you use to generate a second request and lead to a second callback function to scrape the second level. In abstract that sounds complex, but you will see from [the example code in the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) that it is quite straightforward.

Furthermore, the [CrawlSpider example](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#crawlspider-example) is more fleshed out and gives you template code that you may simply want to adapt to your situation.

Hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

you can crawl more pages by using the `CrawlSpider` which can be imported from `scrapy.contrib.spiders` and defining your `rules` as to which type of links you want your crawler to scrape.

Follow the notes [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) on how to define your rules

By the way, consider changing function name, from docs:

> Warning
>
> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.